# Receive print content of another class at execution time not after the end of the function

Tags: python, function

What I have tried:

```
import import_ipynb
import time

class A:
    def func1(self):
        for i in range(0, 5):
            print(i)
            time.sleep(1)

class B:
    print('Time is:', A().func1())
```

In `class B` I want to get `print` content in `class A` and add `'Time is:'` to the beginning and print it in console. One solution is to return `i` as a list at the end of function, but I want `i` as instantaneous, not when the function is fully executed. The code I wrote does not do this correctly.
The output I want is:

```
Time is: 0
Time is: 1
Time is: 2
Time is: 3
Time is: 4
```

Comment: You can replace `sys.stdout` with an object that has a `.write()` method; this will be called one or more times with the strings that `print()` is trying to output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want to just change `print(i)` to `print(f"Time is: {i}")`, you can `yield i` from the function, then print at the callsite:

```
import time

def func1():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        yield i
        time.sleep(1)

for i in func1():
    print(f"Time is: {i}")
```

I got rid of the classes since neither was directly relevant to the problem.

`yield` turns `func1` into a generator function. Calling `func1` returns a generator that produces values as needed.

Answer (score 0):

there is a couple of ways to do it, one is making it generator as Carcigenicate show, another one a making your function more customisable

```
import time

def func1(sufix=""):
    for i in range(5):
        print(sufix,i)
        time.sleep(1)


func1("Time is: ")
```